# Windows user account has disappeared from Welcome screen

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

My switch user account has disappeared. If I go to User Accounts in the Control Panel, trying to restore it says my Welcome and Switch user has been disabled.  How can I fix this? I don't want other users to be able to see my files.

Comment: It also looks like your caps lock key was broken.  But you you're not very clear: is it just fast user switching that's disabled, or you do you have a user account named "switch"? Or does the computer never ask for a login at all any more and just boot right to a desktop?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/accessibility/fastuserswitching.mspx that should help you get it turned back on.